# Speed up matrix multiplication when result is known to be symmetric

Tags: r, rcpp

I know that the result of a matrix multiplication is symmetric. Is there an R package or some standard method by which I can speed up my calculations by only calculating the lower/upper half triangle and then copying the result to the other half.

I know that `tcrossprod` benefits from this fact when only one argument is supplied but I want to supply two matrices.

Here is an example where the result is symmetric:

```
n <- 100
m <- 200
s<-matrix(runif(n^2),n,n)
s[lower.tri(s)] <- t(s)[lower.tri(s)]
x <- matrix(runif(m*n), m, n)
x %*% s %*% t(x)
```

`tcrossprod` doesn't seem to be the solution:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(x %*% s %*% t(x), tcrossprod(x %*% s, x))
```

I have attempted to use Rcpp and, even without the copying step, this is slower than R's multiplication (although I freely admit that I am a beginner c++/Rcpp user):

```
w <- s %*% t(x)
mm = Rcpp::cppFunction(
'NumericMatrix mmult(NumericMatrix m , NumericMatrix v)
{
  NumericMatrix out(m.nrow(), v.ncol());

  for (int i = 0; i < m.nrow(); i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
    {
      for(int k = 0; k < m.ncol(); k++){
        out(i,j) += m(i,k) * v(k,j) ;
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
}'
)

microbenchmark(mm(x, w), x %*% w)
```

I think this would be solved if the `sym` variable in the [.Internal function](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/array.c) `do_matprod` was exposed and could be set to true by the user. However, I don't really want to mess with things like that...

Comment: Maybe something in the `Matrix` package? It has a symmetric class. or maybe the `matrixStats` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem like the `matrix` package take andvantage the symmetry:

```
> n <- 100
> x <- s <- matrix(runif(n^2),n,n)
> s[lower.tri(s)] <- t(s)[lower.tri(s)]
> 
> library(Matrix)
> s_sym <- Matrix(forceSymmetric(s))
> class(s_sym) # has the symmetric class
[1] "dsyMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"
> 
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(x %*% x, s %*% s, s_sym %*% s_sym)
Unit: microseconds
            expr min  lq mean median  uq  max neval
         x %*% x 461 496  571    528 625 1008   100
         s %*% s 461 499  560    532 572  986   100
 s_sym %*% s_sym 553 568  667    624 701 1117   100
```

There is not any indication that it should in the help file:

> The basic matrix product, `%*%` is implemented for all our Matrix and
>   also for `sparseVector` classes, fully analogously to R’s base matrix
>   and vector objects. The functions `crossprod` and `tcrossprod` are matrix
>   products or “cross products”, ideally implemented efficiently without
>   computing `t(.)`’s unnecessarily. They also return `symmetricMatrix`
>   classed matrices when easily detectable, e.g., in `crossprod(m)`, the
>   one argument case. `tcrossprod()` takes the cross-product of the
>   transpose of a matrix. `tcrossprod(x)` is formally equivalent to, but
>   faster than, the call `x %*% t(x)`, and so is `tcrossprod(x, y)` instead
>   of `x %*% t(y)`.

A solution for you is to make wrapper functions using `Rcpp` and the BLAS functions available in `R_ext/BLAS.h`. You can do this as follows: make a `func.cpp` like this one:

```
// added to get $(BLAS_LIBS) in compile flags
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <R_ext/BLAS.h>

/*
  Wrapper for BLAS dsymm. See dsymm http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d54/group__double__blas__level3_ga253c8edb8b21d1b5b1783725c2a6b692.html#ga253c8edb8b21d1b5b1783725c2a6b692
  Only works with side = 'R'
  Note intput is by refernce with &
*/
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix blas_dsymm(
    char uplo, int m, int n, double alpha,
    const Rcpp::NumericMatrix &A, const Rcpp::NumericMatrix &B){
  // set lda, ldb and ldc
  int lda = n, ldb = m, ldc = m;

  // make new matrix with dim(m, n)
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix C(m, n); // default values are zero
  double beta = 0;

  F77_NAME(dsymm)(
    "R" /* side */, &uplo, &m, &n, &alpha, 
    A.begin(), &lda, B.begin(), &ldb, &beta, C.begin(), &ldc);

  return(C);
}
```

Then run the following R script:

```
> n <- 100
> m <- 200
> s<-matrix(runif(n^2),n,n)
> s[lower.tri(s)] <- t(s)[lower.tri(s)]
> x <- matrix(runif(m*n), m, n)
> 
> library("Rcpp")
> sourceCpp("func.cpp")
> 
> out <- x %*% s
> out_blas <- blas_dsymm(
+   uplo = "U", m = nrow(x), n = ncol(x), 
+   alpha = 1, A = s, B = x)
> 
> all.equal(out, out_blas)
[1] TRUE
> 
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(
+   dense = x %*% s,
+   BLAS = blas_dsymm(
+     uplo = "U", m = nrow(x), n = ncol(x), 
+     alpha = 1, A = s, B = x))
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 dense 880.989 950.3225 1114.744 1066.866 1159.311 2783.213   100
  BLAS 858.866 938.6680 1169.839 1016.495 1225.286 3261.633   100
```

It does not seem to make any difference here. Note that you need to have `RcppArmadillo` and `Rcpp` package installed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have attempted a pure Rcpp solution in the most recent edit but without much luck. How would I use `R_ext/BLAS.h` in this case?

Comment: Good answer showing how to access the BLAS.  That would be the only hope here, but as you show it is difficult to squeeze extra performance out for this question.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. Perhaps the implementation you suggest might out-perform `%*%` for larger matrices, although I've tested on matrices up to 1000 x 1000 and `%*%` is still marginally faster.

Answer (score -1):

Don't recode matrix multiplications with for-loops. 
Linear Algebra Libraries are highly optimized for this and you're likely to be 10 times slower (or worse).

For the matrix computation, you won't gain much (or loose) by using RcppArmadillo or RcppEigen.

If you want to gain, you can change the Math Library you're using, for example using the MKL with [Microsoft R Open](https://mran.microsoft.com/open/).

Comment: The MKL provides a faster BLAS, this is a standard interface and you get that with any R implementation built as a shared library.  Microsoft's R simply bundles the MKL, but you can (under the licensing terms) also add it to other R builds.  Lastly, (Rcpp)Eigen does NOT use the BLAS so the answer is technically wrong here as Eigen does its own thing.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You're right for the MKL. I talked about MRO because it's the easiest way to use the MKL within R. For the Eigen part, you're also right. Yet, I never said that it used the BLAS, I just said that it isn't faster than base R for matrix multiplication (tested on 3 computers since R 3.3.0).